# Index Match not returning correct value

Tags: excel, indexing, match

```
                         tOP                                    
boT     0     29.99     30  60  60  89  90  1000        
0.250   Hold    Hold    40  40  60  60  80  80  
0.290   Hold    Hold    40  40  60  60  80  80      
0.300   Hold    Hold    60  60  80  80  110 110     
0.340   Hold    Hold    60  60  80  80  110 110     
0.350   Hold    Hold    76  76  110 110 150 150     
0.399   Hold    Hold    76  76  110 110 150 150     
0.400   Hold    Hold    90  90  130 130 180 180     
0.449   Hold    Hold    90  90  130 130 180 180     
0.450   Hold    Hold    100 100 160 160 210 210     
0.490   Hold    Hold    100 100 160 160 210 210     
0.500   Hold    Hold    130 130 190 190 250 250     
0.540   Hold    Hold    130 130 190 190 250 250     
0.550   Hold    Hold    140 140 210 210 280 280     
0.590   Hold    Hold    140 140 210 210 280 280     
0.600   Hold    Hold    250 250 375 375 500 500
```

this is the data table I used

```
=INDEX('sheet1'!$B$3:$I$18,MATCH(boT,'sheet1'!A$4:$A$18,0),MATCH($K$4,'sheet1'!$B$3:$I$3,0))
```

I thought `0` would give the exact match but if I hit a bot of 0.450 and a top of 60 it should be 100 but I'm getting 90 so one level below each time it hits one of the break points.

Comment: Note the mismatch in your ranges: `'sheet1'!$B$3:$I$18` and `'sheet1'!A$4:$A$18,0)`.... row `3` vs. row `4`.

Comment: OMG HAHA THANK YOU MAN! I didn't even see that